# Update only those rows where condition matches criteria based on another table

Tags: sqlite, conditional-statements

I have a table 'TABLE_1' with column 'Encoder'. I have another table 'TABLE_2' with columns 'Start', 'End', 'Offset'. I want to adjust or UPDATE the TABLE_1 by adding the 'Offset' value to 'Encoder'  with the condition iff 'Encoder' >= 'Start' OR <= 'End'. If the criteria fails then do nothing, leave the original 'Encoder' value. here is my code so far. The problem I have is that it updates the rows fine when the condition is met, but places NULL when it does not.

```
Update TABLE_1
    set encoder =
        (
         select (TABLE_1.encoder +TABLE_2.Offset) as NewEncoder
         from TABLE_2
         where 
            TABLE_1.encoder >= TABLE_2.Start 
            and
            TABLE_1.encoder <= TABLE_2.End
         )
```

I expect the final TABLE_1 to have the rows where the condition is NOT met to be unchanged and only update those that met the criteria. Current code updates those that fail the criteria with NULL

Answer (score 0):

Your UPDATE statement needs a WHERE clause with EXISTS:

```
Update TABLE_1
    set encoder =
        (
         select (TABLE_1.encoder +TABLE_2.Offset) as NewEncoder
         from TABLE_2
         where 
            TABLE_1.encoder >= TABLE_2.Start 
            and
            TABLE_1.encoder <= TABLE_2.End
         )
where exists (
  select 1 from TABLE_2
  where 
    TABLE_1.encoder >= TABLE_2.Start 
    and
    TABLE_1.encoder <= TABLE_2.End
)
```

Or use [`coalesce()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#coalesce):

```
Update TABLE_1
    set encoder = coalesce(
        (
         select (TABLE_1.encoder +TABLE_2.Field3) as NewEncoder
         from TABLE_2
         where 
            TABLE_1.encoder >= TABLE_2.Start 
            and
            TABLE_1.encoder <= TABLE_2.End
         )
    , encoder)
```